# How to get the Balance transferred by System to Near Address

Tags: nearprotocol, nearprotocol-validator

When tried to get the balance for one of Address of Near could see that there is some balance transferred from System to the address but could get this data from the mainnet node also in the transaction details.

In the below screenshot I can the balance transferred from system to the address:
[Transaction for Address opp_near_disc.near](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ygvbo.png)

When I tried to get into the transaction hash: 2EKtqebYzGMA6fMsXo7G2roKcxdT1ApbHPNDKo6KYUSq. Could not find any transaction from system : https://nearblocks.io/txns/2EKtqebYzGMA6fMsXo7G2roKcxdT1ApbHPNDKo6KYUSq . It just shows
"Transfer 22,711.66454 Ⓝ From opp_near_disc.near To a7b84e7291...d49f52a".

The same way when I tried with the below curl queries did not get any data related to system:

1.

```
curl --location 'http://10.213.67.4:1332' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data '{
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "id": "dontcare",
  "method": "tx",
  "params": ["2EKtqebYzGMA6fMsXo7G2roKcxdT1ApbHPNDKo6KYUSq",
    "opp_near_disc.near"]
}'
```

2. curl --location 'http://10.213.67.4:1332' 
   --header 'Content-Type: application/json' 
   --data '{
   "jsonrpc": "2.0",
   "id": "dontcare",
   "method": "chunk",
   "params": {"chunk_id": "5KnNTAR6WRvVTmeiU15sqNjfzPWdQqh23ZpmVuxKSd7p"}
   }'

This explorer also does not gives the data: https://explorer.near.org/accounts/opp_near_disc.near .

Please let me know how to get that data.

Answer (score 2):

`system` is a reserved account in NEAR Protocol, and it is used to [refund](https://nomicon.io/Proposals/transaction-refactoring#refunds) NEAR which was pre-paid for transaction gas. There is no balance for this account. It can only be the sender of a receipt with a TRANSFER action (usually small amounts except for the cases when an account gets deleted and the remaining tokens are transferred to the beneficiary account from the `system` account).